# Need help with proof approach for an Integral domain question (Abstract Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra

If n is a positive integer and $_1, _2, _3, _4, \cdots,a_n$ are elements of an integral domain whose product
is zero—i.e. $_1 * _2 * _3 * _4 ⋯ _ = 0$ — show that at least one of the $a’s$ is zero.

I was told to do this question by induction, however, I don’t see where I can apply that method here. Instead, I took the approach by using the definition of Integral domains. By definition, there are no proper divisors of zero, which implies that some $a$ multiplied with the product of the remaining a’s, which we denote by b which is the integral domain, equals zero where a = 0 or $b$ = 0. However I’m not sure if that’s sufficient enough to show that at least one of the a’s must be zero.

Comment: $a_1*(a_2*\ldots*a_n)=0$ implies $a_1=0$ or $a_2*\ldots*a_n=0$. If $a_1=0$ we are done. In case that $a_2*\ldots*a_n=0$ , by the same reasoning $a_2=0$ or $a_3*\ldots*a_n=0$. Repeat inductively.

Comment: It's the same as the inductive proof of the $n$-ary version of Euclid's Lemma in the linked dupe (replace $\,p\mid a\,$ by $\,a = 0\,$  or, equivalently  specialize  $\,p=0,\,$ which is prime in a domain).